# Correcting what was once thought to be correct

Tags: discussion, answers, editing

I asked a question and a user provided an excellent answer in two parts.
I upvoted after trying both parts and was happy with the results.

After much use I picked up that only the first part of his answer was correct, but the second was not.

Would suggesting an edit for his answer be the correct way to update his (already upvoted answer), or would a comment discussion be better?

Answer (score 8):

If you know how to correct the second part and it wouldn't fundamentally change what that part is about, then edit the answer to make it correct. For example, if it contains code that's missing a few parentheses, some variable names are misspelled, it's missing a step in a 5-step procedure, etc. then go ahead and edit.

If it's incorrect and you don't know how to fix it, write a comment that explains what didn't work.

If the second part is fundamentally incorrect (e.g. it makes an assumption that contradicts the facts given in the question), then write a comment that explains what is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using comments to discuss or refine the answer, particularly if the part that is incorrect could be cleaned up to become correct again.

If there is little feedback to correct the answer to something suitable, you can always submit your own answer referencing the correct portion, to clarify what your solution was in the end.